# Two level tabs jquery link

Tags: jquery, tabs, hyperlink

I need to do a link to go to a second level of tabs ( for example , direct acces to the tabs ""direct acces 1 ( in my jsfindle""" )

For the first level , I know I need to do that:

```
 http://aaa.com/index.php#tabs-1
```

But , how can I do for my second level of tabs ? I try  http://aaa.com/index.php#tabs-1#tabs2-1   but its not working.... Is it possible to do this with a link or I need to use some jquery ? Thx !

My jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/a234j/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do some custom logic.  Often hash routes look something like this:

aaa.com/index.php/#/tabs-1/tabs-2

Then, when you do your `location.hash` you need to split it:

```
var hashPath = location.hash.split('/'); //skip the first element, it'll be '#'.
var firstLevel = hashPath[1];
var secondLevel = hashPath[2];
```

Oh, and I don't think the jQuery tabs plugin has native support for this, so you'll have to manually tell it which tab you want active.

Here's a sample of how to manually switch a tab: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...select_a_tab_from_a_text_link_instead_of_clicking_a_tab_itself